# How do you override vim options via comments in a python source code file?

Tags: python, vim

I would like to set some vim options in one file in the comments section.

For example, I would like to set this option in one file

```
set syntax=python
```

The file does not have a .py extension and I am not interested in making my vim installation recognise all files with this extension as python files.

I know this can be done because I have seen it, but my googling for this has not yet been fruitful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're wanting a [modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) syntax, e.g.

```
# vim: set syntax=python:
```

See: [Modeline magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) at Vim Wikia for more details.

Answer (score 13):

I haven't used vim much, but I think what you want is to add a line like the following to the end of your file:

```
# vim: set syntax=python:
```

Comment: correct would be ```# vim: set syntax=python:``` (note the colon)

Comment: @ZyX what does the colon do?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Which one? Colon after `vim` is required for vim to recognize modeline. Trailing colon is required for one-line C-style comments (`/* … */`) and in any other case you want to write something after a vim modeline. Just a habit: as C-style comments (and any other which have both start and end like HTML ones) require writing trailing colon to place comment end marker at the same line you easily get a habit of writing this colon always.

Comment: @nisc Both variants are correct. Though most common one is `# vim: syn=python` (note absence of `set` and trailing colon (I have explained why it is usually written) and shortened form of an option: for some reasons such forms are highly more common).

Comment: @ZyX Actually, the **version with `set` doesn't work at all when there is no trailing `:`** at least with gVim 7.3. Note also: there **must** be a space before the `vim:`

Answer (score 6):

You override the Vim options by adding the modeline near the top or the bottom of the file, such as:

```
// vim: set syntax=python:
```

or:

```
/* vim: set syntax=python: */
```

or like:

```
# vim: set syntax=python ts=4 :
```

Other examples (from [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic#Examples)):

```
// vim: noai:ts=4:sw=4
   -or-
/* vim: noai:ts=4:sw=4
*/
   -or-
/* vim: set noai ts=4 sw=4: */
   -or-
/* vim: set fdm=expr fde=getline(v\:lnum)=~'{'?'>1'\:'1': */
```

Here is the example which I'm using (on the last line of the file):

```
# vim: set ts=2 sts=2 et sw=2 ft=python:
```

Few highlights:

- Vim executes a modeline only when `modeline` is set to `modeline` or a possitive integer and you're not root (some OS such as Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo, OSX, etc. disable modelines by default for security reasons), so you need to add `set modeline` into your `~/.vimrc` file (`:e $MYVIMRC`),
- the line must be in the first or last few lines,
- space between the opening comment and `vim:` is required,
- location where vim checks for the modeline is controlled by the `modelines` variable (see:  `:help 'modelines'`),
- with `set`, the modeline ends at the first colon (`:`),
- text other than "vim:" can be recognised as a modeline.

Related:

- [Modeline magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) at Vim wikia
- [Vim modeline vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36001/11825) at SS or Google: *vim modeline vulnerability*

Comment: interesting by currently I can't change the options with the file comment, strangely, di you know why?